# Cancelling Forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I have a question about canceling forces that my teacher gave me. I have sketched out the image in the question below.

The grey bar on the mechanism below is anchored and the joints are shown in black. Will the forces provided by the springs on the mechanism cancel? If a 20N weight is placed on the hook, can it be moved by the mechanism with minimal resistance?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The forces exerted by the springs on the mechanism (which is defined as the combination of the four bars connected by joints) are *internal* forces. They can not cause the mechanism as a whole to accelerate. Only *external* forces can do that (such as gravity).

I'm not sure what your teacher means by "cancelling forces". There is no acceleration of the mechanism due to the spring forces because they are internal forces, and the springs would have no effect on a 20 N weight attached to the hook. The two springs are in tension and can cause compressive and bending stresses in the members of the mechanism. Then it becomes a mechanics of deformable solids problem.

Hope this helps.